# in-addr.arpa zone delegation in Bind 9 and Samba 4 as an AD DC with DDNS

Tags: active-directory, reverse-dns, dhcp-server, samba4, ddns

## Environment and goals

In my testing KVM lab I have a virtual network `172.16.50/24`, in this network I have got 2 Centos 7 VMs running Bind 9 and ISC DHCP servers:

- Мастер DNS : `controller.wsvirt.home (172.16.50.2)`
- Slave DNS: `controller2.wsvirt.home (172.16.50.3)`

All clients in the network are Linux VMs and all of the them get network configuration from the DHCP server. This server dynamically updates DNS zones.

Bind 9 is an authoritative server for `wsvirt.home` zone.

In the lab environment I test a scenario which I have to implement in our business office network. In the business environment I should create an AD domain to serve Windows clients and for this purpose we have decided to utilize Samba 4 as a DC. I have built a Samba server for Centos 7 with Heimdal Kerberos support from the sources.

For the AD I allocated subnetwork `172.16.50.192/26` and assigned `ad.wsvirt.home` domain.

AD DC is a Centos 7 VM running Samba 4, Bind 9 and ISC DHCP servers. Samba makes use of BIND_DLZ as a DNS backend. AD controller has `addc1.ad.wsvirt.home` domain name and `IP 172.16.50.193`.

All Windows AD clients get IP from the DHCP server running on the AD DC which dynamically updates Bind DLZ zones.

In the real working physical environment all client PCs from the both networks should be connected to one broadcast domain.

To satisfy the requirements I delegated authority for the forward `ad.wsvirt.home` and reverse `172.16.50.192/26` DNS zones from the Bind on the `controller.wsvirt.home` server to the AD controller `addc1.ad.wsvirt.home` accordingly to [RFC 2317](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2317).

# Problem #

Everything works perfectly except one thing. When I test revers lookup for delegated reverse zone over AD DC then result looks OK, thus Windows AD client could resolve all reverse domain name in both domains. :

```
$ dig -x 172.16.50.193 @addc1.ad.wsvirt.home

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> -x 172.16.50.193 @addc1.ad.wsvirt.home
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43507
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;193.50.16.172.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
193.50.16.172.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN    CNAME   193.50.16.172.ddns.
193.50.16.172.ddns.     900     IN      PTR     addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.50.193#53(172.16.50.193)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 30 21:05:12 IDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 121
```

But when I route my requests to the DNS server `controller.wsvirt.home` it does not resolve any reverse name from the `ad.wsvirt.home` domain, consequently the Linux clients could not lookup any reverse name as well:

```
$ dig -x 172.16.50.193 @controller.wsvirt.home

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> -x 172.16.50.193 @controller.wsvirt.home
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 48825
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;193.50.16.172.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
193.50.16.172.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN    CNAME   193.50.16.172.ddns.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       8133    IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020033001 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.50.2#53(172.16.50.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 30 21:49:41 IDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 162
```

**I need** Linux clients from the `wsvirt.home` domain to be able to resolve reverse domain names in the `ad.wsvirt.home` domain. Is it possible at all?

## Configurations

To be more precise I put here my configuration files for both servers

### Server controller.wsvirt.home

#### /etc/named.conf

```
acl local { 172.16.50.0/24; 127.0.0.1; };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/etc/rndc.key";

server 172.16.50.3 {
        keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

...

options {
        listen-on port 53 { local; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { local; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
        notify no; 
        forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
        forward only;
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};


zone "." IN {
        type hint; 
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "wsvirt.home" IN {
        type master;
        file "wsvirt.home.db";
        allow-update { key "rndc-key"; };
        allow-transfer { key "rndc-key"; };
        notify yes;
        forwarders {};
};

zone "50.16.172.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "50.16.172.db";
        allow-update { key "rndc-key"; };
        allow-transfer { key "rndc-key"; };
        notify yes;
};
```

#### /var/named/50.16.172.db

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
50.16.172.in-addr.arpa  IN SOA  controller.wsvirt.home. root.wsvirt.home. (
                                153        ; serial
                                3600       ; refresh (1 hour)
                                1800       ; retry (30 minutes)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                        NS      controller.wsvirt.home.
                        NS      controller2.wsvirt.home.
$ORIGIN 50.16.172.in-addr.arpa.
2                       PTR     controller.wsvirt.home.
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
3                       PTR     controller2.wsvirt.home.
...
;
50.16.172.ddns.         IN      NS      addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.
$GENERATE 193-254 $     IN      CNAME   $.50.16.172.ddns.
```

#### /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
include "/etc/rndc.key";

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
ddns-update-style interim;

class "windows" {  
        match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 8) = "MSFT 5.0";
}

subnet 172.16.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        log (info, concat("Vendor Class ID (60): ", option vendor-class-identifier));
        log (info, concat("DHCP Client ID (61): ", option dhcp-client-identifier));
        log (info, concat("User Class ID (77): ", option user-class));
        option domain-name-servers 172.16.50.2, 172.16.50.3;
        option ntp-servers 172.16.50.2;
        option routers 172.16.50.1;
        option broadcast-address 172.16.50.255;
        default-lease-time 600;
        max-lease-time 7200;
        option ip-forwarding off;
        ignore client-updates;
        option domain-name "wsvirt.home";
        option domain-search "wsvirt.home";
        option netbios-scope "";
        option netbios-node-type 8;
        option netbios-name-servers 172.16.50.2;
        option netbios-dd-server 172.16.50.2;
        ddns-updates on;
        ddns-domainname "wsvirt.home.";
        ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";

        pool {  
                range 172.16.50.21 172.16.50.190;
                deny members of "windows";
        }

        zone wsvirt.home {
                primary 172.16.50.2;
                key "rndc-key";
        }

        zone 50.16.172.in-addr.arpa {
                primary 172.16.50.2;
                key "rndc-key";
        }
}
```

### AD DC addc1.ad.wsvirt.home

#### /etc/named.conf

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    allow-query     { any; };
    forwarders  { 172.16.50.2; 172.16.50.3; };
    forward only;
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-enable no;
    dnssec-validation no;
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
    tkey-gssapi-keytab "/var/lib/samba/private/dns.keytab";
    minimal-responses yes;
};

...

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
include "/var/lib/samba/bind-dns/named.conf";
```

#### /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
include "/etc/rndc.key";

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
min-secs 5;
authoritative;
ddns-update-style none;

class "others" {
    match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 8) != "MSFT 5.0";
}

subnet 172.16.50.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 {
    log (info, concat("Vendor Class ID (60): ", option vendor-class-identifier));
    log (info, concat("DHCP Client ID (61): ", option dhcp-client-identifier));
    log (info, concat("User Class ID (77): ", option user-class));
    option routers 172.16.50.1;
    option broadcast-address 172.16.50.255;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option ip-forwarding off;
    ignore client-updates;
    option ntp-servers 172.16.50.193;
    option domain-name-servers 172.16.50.193;
    option domain-name "ad.wsvirt.home";
    option domain-search "ad.wsvirt.home";
    option netbios-name-servers 172.16.50.193;
    option netbios-dd-server 172.16.50.193;
    option netbios-scope "";
    option netbios-node-type 8;
    ddns-rev-domainname "ddns";

    pool {
        range 172.16.50.210 172.16.50.254;
        deny members of "others";
    }
}

on commit {
    set noname = concat("dhcp-", binary-to-ascii(10, 8, "-", leased-address));
    set ClientIP = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
    set ClientDHCID = concat (
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,1,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,2,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,3,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,4,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,5,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,6,1))),2)
    );
    set ClientName = pick-first-value(option host-name, config-option-host-name, client-name, noname);
    log(concat("Commit: IP: ", ClientIP, " DHCID: ", ClientDHCID, " Name: ", ClientName));
    execute("/usr/local/sbin/dhcp-dyndns.sh", "add", ClientIP, ClientDHCID, ClientName);
}

on release {  
    set ClientIP = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
    set ClientDHCID = concat (
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,1,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,2,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,3,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,4,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,5,1))),2), ":",
    suffix (concat ("0", binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "", substring(hardware,6,1))),2)
    );
    log(concat("Release: IP: ", ClientIP));
    execute("/usr/local/sbin/dhcp-dyndns.sh", "delete", ClientIP, ClientDHCID);
}

on expiry {   
    set ClientIP = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
    log(concat("Expired: IP: ", ClientIP));
    execute("/usr/local/sbin/dhcp-dyndns.sh", "delete", ClientIP, "", "0");
}
```

#### A DLZ revers zone 50.16.172.ddns on the AD DC

```
$ samba-tool dns query localhost 50.16.172.ddns @ ALL 
Password for [administrator@AD.WSVIRT.HOME]:
  Name=, Records=2, Children=0
    SOA: serial=3, refresh=900, retry=600, expire=86400, minttl=3600, ns=addc1.ad.wsvirt.home., email=hostmaster.ad.wsvirt.home. (flags=600000f0, serial=3, ttl=3600)
    NS: addc1.ad.wsvirt.home. (flags=600000f0, serial=1, ttl=3600)
  Name=193, Records=1, Children=0
    PTR: addc1.ad.wsvirt.home (flags=f0, serial=3, ttl=900)
  Name=230, Records=1, Children=0
    PTR: winxp-1.ad.wsvirt.home (flags=f0, serial=3, ttl=3600)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have discovered a root of the problem. The point is that Bind 9 strips away DNSSEC signatures, when it works as a forwarder. I knew it, so in the `named.conf` at the server `addc1.ad.wsvirt.home` I set the following options as a workaround:

```
dnssec-enable no; 
dnssec-validation no;
```

But I forgot to do the same at the `controller.wsvirt.home`, now I have fixed my oversight and everything works good. And obviously the zone section for the `50.16.172.ddns` must be in the Bind's config file at the `addc1.ad.wsvirt.home` server:

```
zone "50.16.172.ddns." { 
    type forward; 
    forwarders { 172.16.50.193; }; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal not to get the `PTR` on the same answer, as the `controller.wsvirt.home.` isn't an *authoritative* name server for both zones. The `flags: aa` states that this is an authoritative answer, but that wouldn't be true for `193.50.16.172.ddns. IN PTR`. Therefore, **it can't be sent on this authoritative answer**.

This is not really a problem, because that only causes another query for `193.50.16.172.ddns. IN PTR`, which could then be answered recursively. Clients should be aware of doing this automatically in case of a `CNAME` answer.

Regarding that, there's **another problem**, as only `addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.` has zone `50.16.172.ddns.`; you would get an `NXDOMAIN` answer on:

```
dig 193.50.16.172.ddns. PTR @controller.wsvirt.home
```

The `controller.wsvirt.home.` is configured as recursive (`recursion yes;`), but it's not aware that these addresses could be found on `addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.`. Therefore, it tries to resolve them as everything else: from the `forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };`... and fails.

You could add the `addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.` as a forwarder for `50.16.172.ddns.` on the `controller.wsvirt.home.`:

```
zone "50.16.172.ddns." { 
    type forward; 
    forwarders { 172.16.50.193; }; 
};
```

---

Finally, the zone for `$ORIGIN 50.16.172.in-addr.arpa.` could only delegate control for its own subdomains – not for a completely unrelated `50.16.172.ddns.`.

If you really still want to send the `PTR` on the same response, you need to make this domain authoritative for `50.16.172.ddns.` by adding a `slave` zone (instead of a `forward` zone), e.g.

```
zone "50.16.172.ddns." { 
    type slave;
    file "50.16.172.ddns.db";
    masters { 172.16.50.193; }; 
};
```

The primary server (`addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.`) needs to be aware of this and allow zone transfers from `controller.wsvirt.home.` (and `controller2.wsvirt.home`, if it should act similarly):

```
options {
    . . .
    allow-transfer { 172.16.50.2; 172.16.50.3; };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bu it does not help. I have played around with forwarding and got the same result when digging.

Comment: Additionally I have to mention that RFC 2317 does nor require to do anything with forwarding it rather suggests to make an alias to delegated revers zone therefore on the controller.wsvirt.home I have in the reverse zone file /var/named/50.16.172.db the following lines: 50.16.172.ddns.         IN      NS      addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.
$GENERATE 193-254 $     IN      CNAME   $.50.16.172.ddns.

Comment: But `50.16.172.ddns.` is not a subdomain of `50.16.172.in-addr.arpa.`, so it can't delegate control of it to other name server...

Comment: Anyway the forwarding doesn't help.

Comment: I think now I understood your concern: I only saw a real problem in your configuration, not the one you were explaining you are having. Now my answer should have the full picture.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification I hope I understood your advise correctly and did as you suggest, the result I have described below in my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use MY script, please use it correctly ;-)

Run Bind9 and isc-dhcp on the DC, no where else.
See here:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_BIND_DNS_Server

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_DHCP_to_update_DNS_records_with_BIND9

One of your main problems is that you are trying to store the reverse zone in a 'flatfile' and bind9_dlz does not work with flatfiles.

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your grate script, it works good and I used mentioned guides as a major reference. Now I have to admit that Samba, Bind and DHCP servers run on the same system. And finally, would you tell me please why do you think that I store my reverse zone's RRs  in a flat file?

Comment: Because things like :

zone "50.16.172.ddns." { 
    type slave;
    file "slaves/50.16.172.ddns.db";
    masters { 172.16.50.193; }; 
};

Are flatfiles and do not work with bind9_dlz.

Follow the samba wiki and it will work, well it has for me for the last 8 years.

Comment: I don't use such lines at all. If you look closely at the posts above you could see that Esa Jokinenn advises to put these lines in the Bind's config, not me. I only tried it  once unsuccessfully following the advise. By the way I have decided the issue, look my post below.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the Esa Jokinen's suggestion I did the following:

On the **controller.wsvirt.home** in the `/etc/named.conf` I created a zone section for `50.16.172.ddns`.

```
zone "50.16.172.ddns." { 
    type slave;
    file "slaves/50.16.172.ddns.db";
    masters { 172.16.50.193; }; 
};
```

In the zone file `/var/named/50.16.172.db` I commented out the lines delegating the `50.16.172.ddns` zone:

```
;50.16.172.ddns.                IN      NS      addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.
;$GENERATE 193-254 $    IN      CNAME   $.50.16.172.ddns.
```

On the **addc1.ad.wsvirt.home.** in the `/etc/named.conf`:

```
options {
    . . .
    allow-transfer { 172.16.50.2; 172.16.50.3; };
}
```

As a result I have an authority for the zone `50.16.172.ddns` but **revers names got unresolved at all**:

```
dig -x 172.16.50.193 @addc1.ad.wsvirt.home

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> -x 172.16.50.193 @addc1.ad.wsvirt.home
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 30147
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;193.50.16.172.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
50.16.172.in-addr.arpa. 10800   IN      SOA     controller.wsvirt.home. root.wsvirt.home. 154 3600 1800 604800 86400

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.50.193#53(172.16.50.193)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 01 17:20:44 IDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118
```

```
$ dig -x 172.16.50.193 

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> -x 172.16.50.193
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 62725
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;193.50.16.172.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
50.16.172.in-addr.arpa. 86400   IN      SOA     controller.wsvirt.home. root.wsvirt.home. 154 3600 1800 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.50.2#53(172.16.50.2)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 01 17:20:56 IDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118
```